# iOS uiwebbiew image gallery

Tags: ios6, uiwebview, image-gallery

Due to resource issues I have to develop an app with uiwebview. There is a part where user has a gallery. I have read that it is possible for users to upload images from their phone gallery via the [input type=file].

Is there any solution where the app can store the images locally to the user phone without user intervention, and images stored are accessible by my app only?
So that on every view of the webpage gallery, I can load the Stored images into the uiwebview rather than having the user to download the same images every time.

Edit

Based on the first comment, I have gathered more. Pls correct me if I am wrong.

The app can download the webpage gallery images to the app document directory. This directory is only accessible by my app in unrooted iPhone.

When user access the webpage gallery, I can download the HTML into document directory also, and serve it to the uiwebview. Inside the HTML the image tags are pointing to the images in the document directory.

Comment: Look into HTML5 storage. If this is not enough, you need to implement a middleman in your app to serve content from the app's filesystem directory to the webview.

Comment: How the middleman works. That's seems like what I need to do. Serve images from app filesystem to the webview.